# How do I combine both without any loop?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

```
$data1 = "mathews,luks,john,ethan,neil";

$data2 = "80%,60%,78%,55%,62%";
```

want to combine both like

```
mathews = 80%
Luks    = 60%
John    = 78%
```

etc.... how to do this?? I want print result exactly like `Mathews = 80%`

Comment: just asking if any other option...or else loop will do

Comment: Why don't you want to use a loop??

Comment: Whats wrong with a loop? if you aren't going to use a loop you will need to hardcode the values.

Comment: looking for various and easy options rather complex

Comment: ok no issues loop will do but which is the optimized one? in terms of coding?

Comment: What do you mean by "optimized"? Premature optimization is bad for your health...

Comment: Premature optimization is bad, agreed. But I also a agree coding a loop to achieve something that php offers natively with array_combine is also bad for your health. I applaud you for looking for solutions that appeal to the strengths of a language, and taking the time to learn how to best use the tools each language offers.  Understandably, coming from a different background looping would be you first thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

$result = array_combine ( explode ( ',', $data1 ), explode ( ',', $data2 );

to extract:

- if you know key name: echo $result ['john'];
- if all: foreach ( $result as $key => $value ) { echo $key . ' : ' . $value; }
- to gey list of keys: $list = explode ( ',', $data1 ) or $list = array_keys ( $result );
  http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: but here how do I extract array like this....mathew = 80% ?? every time names gonna change

Comment: this is why I said no know key names...I want print names = value

Comment: foreach ( $result as $key => $value ) { echo $key . ' = ' . $value; }

Comment: or you can use array_walk if you want be more robust: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Answer (score 2):

How about this...?

```
print_r(array_combine(explode(',',$data1),explode(',',$data2)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array_combine(explode(',', $data1), explode(',', $data2));
```

Or

```
$names = explode(',', $data1);
$par   = explode(',', $data2);
$arr   = array();
foreach ($names as $idx=>$name)
{
  $arr[$name] = $par[$idx];
}
```

Comment: from OP - `ok no issues loop will do but which is the optimized one? in terms of coding?`, this is too sub-optimize

Comment: $arr[$name] did nto return any values

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in [array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you are some kind of anti-loop fanatic, you could create a recursive function.

```
function no_loop_combine($data1,$data2,$index)
{
    if($index == count($data1))
    {
        return '';
    }
    else
    {
        return $data1[$index] . ' = ' . $data2[index]
                . '\n' . no_loop_combine($data1,$data2,$index + 1);
    }
}
```

Then you just have to call your function specifying $index = 0, and you will get the result.  Using array_combine probably is still using a loop, just masked by the fact that you are calling a function.  Using recursion means there is no loop. Just realized that your initial input is a string, and not a loop.  So you could call explode before passing it into the function as so:

```
no_loop_combine(explode(',', $data1 ),explode(',',$data2),0);
```

Comment: This would be the implementation of a pseudo-loop; hence the execution time won't get reduced and still be O(n).

Comment: I didn't say execution time would be reduced.  Simply expressed a way of doing it without a loop.  Calling array_combine still uses a loop, just that the loop is hidden within the function call.  That doesn't mean calling array_combine isn't also O(n).  I have a proof that any method of solving this problem would be at least O(n), but the comments area is too small to fit it.

Comment: yeah I was just checking for various options and I believe thats why we all are here...

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using `preg_split` to the string:

```
$names = preg_split("/[,]+/", "mathews,luks,john,ethan,neil");
$percent = preg_split("/[,]+/", "80%,60%,78%,55%,62%");
```

Then you can use `array_combine` like many others suggest, or simply use 2 arrays $names and $percent along with the shared index, for example, $names[2] goes along with $percent[2].

Answer (score 0):

As stated by bensui:

```
$data1 = "mathews,luks,john,ethan,neil";
$data2 = "80%,60%,78%,55%,62%";
$array = array_combine(explode(',',$data1), explode(',',$data2));
```

This will result in:

```
print_r($array);
Array
(
    [mathews] => 80%
    [luks] => 60%
    [john] => 78%
    [ethan] => 55%
    [neil] => 62%
)
```

This will give you the ability easily update the assocaited scores simple by doing:

```
$array['mathews'] = '90%';
```

You can then use the array_slice I offered you earlier to discard john and ethan:

```
$newArray = array_slice($array, 2, 2);
```

This will give you:

```
print_r($newArray);
Array
(
    [mathews] => 80%
    [luks] => 60%
    [neil] => 62%
)
```

Note: there is nothing wrong with using loops, the fact of the matter is they are often over used when there are methods built in to the language to solve many common problems.

Comment: I want print result like this "Mathews = 80% "

Comment: To print a single record you can: echo 'Mathews = ' . $array['mathews'];

Comment: To print them all like a list, you need to loop though the array foreach($array as $name => score) echo "$name = $score";